# Why didn't Windows 10 ever try to force itself onto my machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

My attempts to search for an answer only lead me to problems, complaints, and workarounds regarding the upgrade process.

I don't want a fix for this. I'm just curious about the cause.

I have a Cyberpower desktop I got a few years ago. It has Windows 7 and I keep it on. It's always on the network. (Come to think of it, I keep it on out of habit because I used to run a Minecraft server on it. I should turn it off.)

It does automatically run updates and reboot itself from time to time, but it has never once even mentioned an upgrade to 10. It's as if the whole Windows 10 crisis doesn't exist.

I'm grateful but curious anyway. What's going on?

I know you'll probably need information about my computer to answer this question. I'll gladly give it. I just don't know what information is relevant. It can't possibly have anything to do with the hardware, can it? Maybe it's in the settings, but what are the chances I just naturally set everything perfectly?

**Edit**

Specs:

- Manufacturer:     CyberPower Inc.
- Rating:           5.9 Windows Experience Index
- Processor:        Intel Core i7-3820 3.60 GHz
- Installed Memory: 8.00 GB
- System Type:      64-bit Operating System
- Video:            GeForce GTX 750 4GB

**Edit 2**

I do have SP1.

**Edit 3**

I'm not looking for a fix. I just want to know why this has happened.

**Edit 4**

The flavor of Windows 7 on my machine is Home Premium.

**Edit 5**

Under **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows** I have neither **WindowsUpdate** nor **Gwx**.

The policy path found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3080351) doesn't seem to be available when I run mmc. Is that where I'm supposed to look?

Comment: My best guess is that it wasn't judged powerful enough to run Windows 10 smoothly. What are its specs?

Comment: @BenN doesn't Windows 10 have the same reqs as 7?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Windows 10 requires certain CPU capabilities/instructions (notably NX), which I don't think Windows 7 needs.

Comment: @BenN ah. That could be the reason.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - It actually isn't the reason, the processor the author has, fully supports Windows 8.1+

Comment: @MackTuesday - This is an easy problem to solve.  Download .ISO and update to Windows 10, the upgrade process is identical, there are literally dozens of reasons why the upgrade wouldn't be offered to you machine.

Comment: @Ramhound that info wasn't there at the time.

Comment: Which edition of windows? The most obvious reason that comes to mind is that the Enterprise edition does not get automatic upgrades. You can see the edition in the "System" view of the Control Panel, or in `winver`. Home, Pro[fessional], Ultimate, and their various minor variations (like the "N" editions) should all get the automatic upgrade, but I believe Enterprise does not.

Comment: @CBHacking -- Home Premium.

Comment: Do you have GWX.exe in your machine?  Do you have all the required patches?  Do you have the patch, that installed, GWX.exe?  If you start GWX.exe what happens?  Can you verify the registry edits to block GWX.exe and the upgrade have not been applied?  Provide screenshots for all this information if you don't mind.

Comment: Do you have a registry entry `DWORD value: DisableGwx = 1` in `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Gwx` by any chance, or anything related to [How to manage Windows 10 notification and upgrade options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3080351)?

Comment: @Ramhound -- Answers in Edit 5.

Comment: @dxiv -- Answers in Edit 5.

Comment: @MackTuesday `Edit 5` That means that KB 3080351 wasn't installed, which eliminates another reason why the notification wouldn't show up.

Comment: You never installed the required updates to get a windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound -- Thanks. Do you know why they weren't installed automatically? Or is that another question?

Comment: It is your system.  You tell us?

Comment: @Ramhound -- I was hoping for help in diagnosing the reason because I didn't turn off updates completely, but you're right. I need to some research myself before I ask more questions.

Comment: There are any number of reasons the update would be blocked, including, actions taken by you that.  Far to many to list.  Install the update and you will be asked to upgrade though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is some problem with the windows update.

You can try fixing it with troubleshooter.

Another thing is the update cache and dumps, you can delete them by navigating to `c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution` and delete all files and folders.

Restart your PC and check for updates.

If it doesn't work, try media creation tool.

As you have aleady said that you are not interested in getting the update, still start it and select upgrade this pc it will check your system and report the problem.

You can then cancel the process.

Answer (score -1):

So I remember this as an issue in a couple different way. Firstly you had to meet certain requirements. (Windows 7 on SP1, running genuine windows OS). You can read about that here. It does have a resolution option, but if this isn't you issue it probably wont help.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3081048

Another problem that caused headaches was that the files would download in the background, sometimes... they would get stuck. Follow this guide to manually remove the failed windows 10 download.

http://www.alphr.com/microsoft/1001411/how-to-fix-windows-update-in-windows-10-if-it-becomes-stuck

One of these should fix your issue. Even if your PC is horribly out of date and the hardware isn't supported.. you should get the prompt to check for windows 10 compatibility. My mother in laws PC has an old celeron CPU and the compatibility checker failed her because her desktop is about 12 years old.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but I'm actually quite happy the upgrade never happened! I'm really just curious about why. I looked at your links. I do have SP1. It looks like the other link would help with diagnosis, but not without doing something that might "fix" the "problem".

Comment: HA! I have to be honest, I went from windows 7 to windows 10 and the transition has been seamless. I mean, if you don't mind Microsoft watching everything you do...Every breath you take. Every Move you Make...

Comment: Indeed. I have 10 on a new machine and still haven't sold Cortana my soul.